# ASP.NET Core 6 OData Swagger UI always shows $count query

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, odata

I created a new ASP.NET Core Web API project with Swagger and added an `ODataController`. The Swagger UI shows my `Users` route as expected, and it works. But the Swagger UI also unexpectedly shows `Users/$count`:

[image]

Why is `$count` there? Can I prevent it from appearing?

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.0.10 (the latest). I get the same results with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.2.3 (the template default) and 6.3.1 (the latest).

My entire controller:

```
    public class UsersController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly ErpContext _db;

        public UsersController(ErpContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_db.Users);
        }
    }
```

My entire EDM:

```
    public static class EntityDataModel
    {
        public static IEdmModel Build()
        {
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
```

My entire startup, in case there's some order sensitivity or something:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ErpContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);
});
builder.Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddOData(options =>
    {
        options.AddRouteComponents("odata", EntityDataModel.Build());
    });
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Note that my controller action does not have `[EnableQuery]` and my `ODataOptions` does not have `Count()` or any other query. The unwanted `$count` query doesn't even work unless I add those.

I've reproduced the problem in a [minimal project](https://github.com/kjkrum/ODataTest) with an in-memory DB.

Comment: Hi, are you sure you have shared the whole code? By using your current code, I never get the `$count` in my endpoint.

Comment: @Rena The whole code of the default ASP.NET web app template is of course many files. I added a couple more things. Is there something else you think might be relevant?

Comment: @Rena I reproduced it in a minimal project. What package versions are you using?

Comment: Hi @Kevin Krumwiede, I use the same version of your two packages..

Comment: @Rena Are there any glaring differences between your setup and my repro project?